# Setting GPIO using sysfs fails in i.MX6

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, gpio, device-tree, sysfs

I have a custom i.MX6 board, and I want to turn on a particular GPIO.

From the schematic, the GPIO pin is connected to KEY_COL2 pad, and the KEY_COL2 has the following options.

[image]

So, I have to export the following GPIO as per the calculation:

```
linux gpio number = (gpio_bank - 1) * 32 + gpio_bit
```

gpio number =  ( 4 - 1 ) *32 +10 = 106

When I run the following command, i get the error:

```
# echo 106 > /sys/class/gpio/export
sh: write error: Device or resource busy
```

What can be the issue, am i missing anything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at the device tree, this particular GPIO was used by some other device, hence the error.

You can find the GPIO's in use with the following commands:

```
 mount -t debugfs none /sys/kernel/debug

 cat /sys/kernel/debug/gpio
```

Comment: Can be done by calling `gpioinfo` from `libgpiod` tools).